# htaccess mod_rewrite - rewrite folder and file to parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the follow folder structure for images:

```
http://www.localhost/memes/01/blaa.jpg
http://www.localhost/memes/02/blaa2.pg
```

etc.

Now I want to move the structure but the old one must still be available for PHP file.

So it should be rewritten like:

```
http://www.localhost/memes/01/blaa.jpg
```

to:

```
http://www.localhost/memes/?folder=01&pic=blaa.jpg
```

or to:

`http://www.localhost/memes/?pic=blaa.jpg` (ignoring the subfolder of `memes`)

yes it's www.localhost for what ever reason and I don't mind it so far :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^memes/([^/]*)/(.*jpg)$ memes/?folder=$1&pic=$2 [NC,L]
```